# Fail to install nodejs on Windows 8.1

Tags: node.js, windows-installer, installation

I tried to install http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.12.4/node-v0.12.4-x86.msi on Windows 8.1, but failed.
Pop up a windows err msg box something likes "Node.js Setup Wizard ended prematurely because of an error. Your system has not been modified. To install this program at a later time, run Setup Wizard again...".

This is my logfile http://pastebin.com/xedDtxnu

Anyone install nodejs on Windows 8.1 successfully?

Answer (score 0):

It installs fine for me on Win 8.1 Home Premium 64-bit.

Have you tried disabling your virus checker, running the installer as administrator, checking free disc space?